# Restore Nuget Package always Failed in Agent Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, agent

I have Two Build agent named X and Y  in TFS controller.
But when i launched the Build :
1) if it's taken by Agent X the build failed and there is alaways message that missing "The type or namespace name 'GalaSoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"
2) if it's taken by Agent Y the Build Sucess and theres is no issue.

Can you explain what's the probleme.

Comment: To debug that, you can refer to the logs and check if you can find the referenced file on the agent machine (Agent X here). Then check the same thing on Agent Y, compare the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you referenced the files:

If you referenced the file as an absolute path, then you need to copy the files to the specific location on agent machine. In this case you can compare the build logs between Agent X and Agent Y to find the differences, then debug it.

So, generally we recommend referencing a file as a relative path in the project file (.csproj).

To add a relative reference in a separate directory, such as C:\tfs_get\Sources\assembly\abc.dll, do the following:

1. Add the reference in Visual Studio by right clicking the project in
   Solution Explorer and selecting Add Reference.
2. Find the `*.csproj` where this reference exist and open it in a text
   editor. Lets say your .csproj location is `c:\tfs_get\sources\myfolder\myproject\myproj.csproj`
3. Edit the `< HintPath >` to be equal to  `..\..\assembly\abc.dll`

This build will work properly with the assumption that the folders ( assembly, myfolder) under the sources folder exist in TFS.